# how to reuse customer payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a use case for Stripe that I am not sure is possible.  I create Stripe customers (offices) that use a payment method to buy physical products (which I do via paymentIntent).  What I would like to do is reuse that paymentMethod for their users subscriptions.  Ideally, each of these users will have a uniqueId I can store for changes/cancellations.

So it looks like this:

```
- Customer (office) created on Stripe
 -- PaymentIntent created with a default paymentMethod
 -- Subscriptions for the customer customers, using the above paymentMethod
```

I guess it boils down to two questions:

1. Can I reuse the customer paymentMethod to multiple subscriptions
   for the customer customer
2. Do I have to create customer records for the subscription users in order to reuse the original paymentMethod?

UPDATE:
Based upon feedback, I tried setting the customer paymentMethod on the new subscription user.  But the charge is still not automatically applied - I have to go to Stripe dashboard for the customer and approve it there.

To recap:
the customer and payment method is created without issue
the customer original purchase request is processed without issue
I am able to then find the customer via their stripeId, and use to get the PaymentMethod.

I create the subscription but it shows as incomplete until I manually approve it.

Here is how I am using the API to handle the subscription with the stored Stripe customer id:

```
  PaymentMethod pm = PaymentMethod.builder()                            .paymentMethod(paymentMethod.getPaymentMethod())
                        .ownerType(OwnerType.PATIENT)
                        .stripeId(newPatient.getInternalId())
                        .build();
    

  SubscriptionCreateParams.PaymentSettings subscriptionPaymentSettings =
                        SubscriptionCreateParams.PaymentSettings
                       .builder()                                               .setSaveDefaultPaymentMethod(SaveDefaultPaymentMethod.ON_SUBSCRIPTION).build();
 SubscriptionCreateParams subscriptionParams =
         SubscriptionCreateParams.builder()                                    .setCustomer(office.getStripeId())                                            .addItem(SubscriptionCreateParams.Item.builder()                                                                                  .setPrice(subscriptionDTO.getPriceId())                                                                                  .build())
.setDefaultPaymentMethod(pm.getPaymentMethod())
.setPaymentSettings(subscriptionPaymentSettings)
.setCollectionMethod(CollectionMethod.CHARGE_AUTOMATICALLY)  .setPaymentBehavior(SubscriptionCreateParams.PaymentBehavior.DEFAULT_INCOMPLETE)
.addAllExpand(Arrays.asList("latest_invoice.payment_intent"))
.build();

try {
    Stripe.apiKey = API_SECRET_KEY;
   Subscription subscription = Subscription.create(subscriptionParams); 
 } catch (StripeException e) {
   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)  

.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(
                                new ErrorResponse(String.format("Unable to create Stripe customer for %s", subscriper.getFullName())));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Yes you can create multiple Subscriptions for the same Customer.

2/ The key is how you collect and set up the PaymentMethod. If you are using a PaymentIntent to collect the PaymentMethod (and take initial payment) then you want to ensure you use [setup_future_usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-customer) and you pass a [Customer ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-customer) so that the PaymentMethod is properly set up and attached to the Customer to be used again in the future for the Subscription(s).

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can create that flow to confirm for me.

Comment: I was able to reuse the paymentMethod from the office, however it looks like I had to manually approve an invoice in the payment method via a payment link in the console.  Is it possible to have the charge automatically paid when I create the office paymentIntent:  

`PaymentIntent paymentIntent = subscription.getLatestInvoiceObject().getPaymentIntentObject();
            paymentIntent.setConfirmationMethod("automatic");
paymentIntent.confirm();`

Comment: Yes, set the PaymentMethod as the default for the Subscription when you create it: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method

Comment: updated my OP with the results of setting automatic payment method

Comment: You want `payment_behavior: allow_incomplete` if you want the payment attempt to occur automatically on Subscription creation instead of manually confirming the PaymentIntent afterwards.